# Lookup type from generic type can't be assigned to "any"

Tags: typescript

Alright, this one is a bit hard to explain. My example is convoluted but I tried to simplify it as much as possible while retaining the error.

```js
type Handler = (...args: any[]) => void;

const handlers: { [eventName: string]: Handler } = {};

type Events = {
  // Map event signature (arg types) to event name
  [eventName: string]: any[];
};

function createOnEvent<UserEvents extends Events>() {
  type ValidEventName = Extract<keyof UserEvents, string>;

  return <EventName extends ValidEventName>(
    eventName: EventName,
    eventHandler: (...args: UserEvents[EventName]) => void,
  ) => {
    handlers[eventName] = eventHandler; // [0] ERROR HERE
  };
}
```

> [0] Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'UserEvents[EventName]'

Two things confuse me:

- `UserEvents[EventName]` should be equal to `any[]`
- I'm trying to assign `UserEvents[EventName]` to `any[]`, not the other way around...

Btw, this is how this API is used:

```js
type FooEvents = {
  eventOne: [number];
  eventTwo: [string, boolean];
};

const onEvent = createOnEvent<FooEvents>();
onEvent('eventOne', (arg1: number) => null); // OK
onEvent('eventTwo', (arg1: string, arg2: boolean) => null); // OK
onEvent('eventOne', (arg1: string) => null); // error
```

Which works as expected. The only part that fails is when I want to store the handler in `handlers`, which should expect functions with any list of args.

I realize this is a bit confusing, so let me know if I can clarify anything. I'd be great to get to the bottom of this. Thanks!

Comment: Which version of TypeScript are you using? It works without error with TypeScript 3.2.1.

Comment: @KarolMajewski The error seems to occur only with `--strictFunctionTypes` flag. Let me know if you understand why. I have `strict` enabled, but I don't know what the implication of this flag is...

Comment: Ah yes! I always forget to enable the flags in the playground. `--strictFunctionTypes ` takes care of proper covariance and contravariance. This blog post does a good job explaining what it is: https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reason**

The error you experience stems from the fact that function types are [contravariant in their argument type](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance) when the `--strictFunctionTypes` flag is used.

What does that mean? It means when a function expects some type for its argument, you are allowed to use an argument as specific or wider than that expected type.

In your case, `handlers` is a dictionary of generic handlers. These handlers expect `any[]` arguments. Their definition could as well have been written like that:

```
const handlers: {
  [eventName: string]: (...args: any[]) => void
} = {};
```

However, your `eventHandler` is not just a generic handler. It does not accept just `any[]` arguments, but some very specific ones described by `UserEvents`. That's against the idea of contravariance — arguments passed to a function must not be more specific than the ones required by its signature. In other words, `typeof eventHandler` is not assignable to `Handler`.

**What you can do**

- Widen the type of `eventHandler` locally by using a type assertion:

  ```
  handlers[eventName] = eventHandler as Handler;
  ```
- Make the compiler accept specific definitions of a handler:

  ```
  type Handler<T extends any[] = any> = (...args: T) => void;
  ```